# specifying external mysql driver for PHP 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have a cluster of servers running apache+mod_python with a MySQL Cluster (NDB) as the database. The code in python uses MySQLdb.

Today I was adding a new package to the web portal that needed PHP. So unaware of the so called mysqlnd internal driver that PHP 5.3 now comes with, I enabled mod_php on the same servers.

This suddenly resulted in total break down of python codes!!! After digging a bit, I noticed that the MySQLdb library is returing integers and other types as string (which the python code is not expecting).

Disabling mod_php from apache fixed it.

My conclusion is that somehow overrides the native mysql driver that handles the NDB stuff in the apache environment and messes up the returns and everything.

Now, my question is that what can I do? Is there a way to tell PHP to use the mysql driver installed in the system and disable the internal mysql driver of it?

Comment: PHP won't use mysqlnd unless you compile it with `--with-mysql=mysqlnd`

Comment: I think this makes more sense on ServerFault.

Comment: It is the standard RedHat RPM. I guess I need to compile from scratch then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet may be using FastCGI and the new [FPM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php) SAPI instead of mod_php.  This detaches PHP itself from Apache, which will prevent the library confusion you're experiencing.

(It's also worth noting that if your Python programs use [WSGI](http://wsgi.org/wsgi/WsgiStart), then you can also use [one of the WSGI-FastCGI adapters](http://wsgi.org/wsgi/Servers) instead of mod_python.)

Comment: I can't use 2 different web servers on same server. First reason coming to mind is that they won't be able to share port 80 and 443. Moreover, these are production environment with a ton of custom code. Moving web server from Apache to something else will require a huge amount of time and effort to test and tune the code (e.g. the code relies heavily on shared objects between threads of mod_python for performance)

Comment: [FastCGI is not a web server](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/), it's an interface between a web server and an application.  You'd still be using Apache, just in combination with another set of code.  If the underlying PHP (or Python) is written correctly, it will never notice the difference.

Comment: I see the logic now. Thanks. I'll give it a try.